# Convert offline copy of webpage in HTML to "Reader View"

Tags: html, converters, reader

I have a local copy of a webpage saved as HTML. I want to convert this HTML file into an output similar to the output of the "reader view" found in modern web browsers.

Is there any tool I could use for this (UNIX-like or Windows)? Preferably I want to use is on a collection of local HTML files.

Thanks in advance.

jmt

Comment: Not that I know. But have you tried to convert it into a pdf file? There are several tools that can do that.

Comment: I want to strip away all the non-essential stuff of the webpage like navigation and leave just the article, just like the "reader mode" in Firefox and Safari does. Converting to PDF will not remove those.

Comment: May have found something after all. See my answer.

Comment: OP here. Thanks for the replies. First of, "Preferably, I want to use is on a collection of local HTML files." was a bad choice of words, as I want to batch process the files. Second, after some research I believe that mozilla/readability is something would could to the job. I do not have the necessary knowledge to use the tool to process local files though, so if this is the right direction, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option that more or less does that: disable CSS. You will then get only the markup, not the makeup. Next, copy and paste the article text. To disable CSS in Chrome, see https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-disable-css-in-chrome. In Firefox, click View > Page Style > No style.

Comment: That won't remove the non-primary content (e.g. navigation menus) or any presentation that comes from markup instead of CSS.

Comment: @Quentin — That’s why I wrote: “Next, copy and paste the article text.”

Comment: The OP is looking for a tool to batch process files, not a manual process.

Comment: @Quentin — “Preferably”. And there is no tool. Plus: with CSS disabled, you can process page after page quite fast.

Comment: OP here. Thank you for the suggestion Frank. Disabling CSS does not provide the same output as the "Reader View", as it still leaves all navigation menus, comments, links at top and bottom of the page. I want to view only the content of an article.